# Improving Groovy list iteration with collect closure

Tags: groovy, closures

I have a functioning Groovy 2.4.3 method that I think I can make even *groovier* by using the `collect()` closure, but not exactly sure how:

```
List<Buzz> deriveBuzzesFromFizz(Fizz fizz) {
    List<Buzz> buzzes = []
    fizz.foobars?.each {
        if(it.label.equals('whistlefeather')) {
            buzzes << it
        }
    }

    buzzes
}
```

Perhaps something like:

```
List<Buzz> buzz = fizz.foobars?.collect {
    it.label.equals('whistlefeather')
}
```

...or thereabouts?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking of a findAll

```
fizz.foobars?.findAll {
    it.label == 'whistlefeather'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - so what's the difference between `findAll` and `collect` (or rather, where are they documented - I can't find any official Groovy docs on them!?!)? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb, you can see groovy Collection's javadoc: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html